# Given year, month, day and monthwise weeknumber, how can I find the date?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have

```
Year : 2011
Month: Nov
Day: Sun
WeekNumber(Monthwise): 4
```

**Desire Output:**

```
Date
--------
2011-11-20
```

How can I do so in a single SQL statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably look at using the `NEXT_DAY` function which returns the first day of the weekday provided that occurs after the date given. Once you've got that, you can then add the required number of weeks.

An example of this might be:

```
with test_data as (
  select
    '2011' as the_year,
    'Nov' as the_month,
    'Sun' as the_day,
    4 as the_week
  from dual
)
select 
  the_year, the_month, the_day, the_week,
  next_day(to_date(the_year||the_month, 'YYYYMON') - 1, the_day) + 
    7* (the_week -1) as the_date
from test_data
```

Answer (score 1):

this may work.

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY( TO_DATE(TO_CHAR((4-1)*7) || '-' || 'NOV' || '-' || '2011','dd-mon-yyyy') ,'Sun') 
FROM DUAL
```

see: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions093.htm

Comment: worked for me, the error is probably because I did not specify a date format, have updated.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
SELECT A.B + B.D YourDate 
FROM (SELECT TO_DATE (Your4DigitYear || LPAD ( YourMonth, 2, '0' ) || LPAD ( DECODE (YourWeekOfMonth, 1, '1', (YourWeekOfMonth - 1) * 7 ), 2, '0' ), 'YYYYMMDD') B FROM DUAL) A, (SELECT LEVEL - 1 D FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 15) B WHERE 
TO_CHAR (A.B + B.D, 'D' ) = YourDayOfWeek AND 
TO_CHAR (A.B + B.D, 'W' ) = YourWeekOfMonth;
```